# Question pairs (ground truth) datasets for Word2Vec model testing?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, word-embedding

I'm looking for test datasets to optimize my Word2Vec model. I have found a good one from gensim:

gensim/test/test_data/questions-words.txt

Does anyone know other similar datasets?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to note that there isn't really a "ground truth" for word-vectors. There are interesting tasks you can do with them, and some arrangements of word-vectors will be better on a specific tasks than others.

But also, the word-vectors that are best on one task – such as analogy-solving in the style of the `questions-words.txt` problems – might not be best on another important task – like say modeling texts for classification or info-retrieval.

That said, you can make your own test data in the same format as `questions-words.txt`.  Google's original `word2vec.c` release, which also included a tool for statistically combining nearby words into multi-word phrases, also included a [`questions-phrases.txt`](https://github.com/tmikolov/word2vec/blob/master/questions-phrases.txt) file, in the same format, that can be used to test word-vectors that have been similarly constructed for 'words' that are actually short multiple-word phrases.

The Python `gensim` word-vectors support includes an extra method, [`evaluate_word_pairs()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.evaluate_word_pairs) for checking word-vectors not on analogy-solving but on conformance to collections of human-determined word-similarity-rankings. The documentation for that method includes a link to an appropriate test-set for that method, [`SimLex-999`](https://fh295.github.io//simlex.html), and you may be able to find other test sets of the same format elsewhere.

But, again, none of these should be considered the absolute test of word-vectors' overall quality. The best test, for your particular project's use of word-vectors, would be some repeatable domain-specific evaluation score you devise yourself, that's inherently correlated to your end goals.

Comment: Thank you very much, you're answer was really helpful !!